# User Input and Output Display

Tags: c

I am making a simple code that will ask a user to input a number; then, the amount will then multiply by itself and display in an output panel saying;

(myNumber) multiplied by (myNumber) equals (myTotal).

However, instead of multiplying itself, the square of the original number is multiplied. How can I make it to where the number is multiplied by itself instead of its square.

Here's my code:

```
       #include <stdio.h>
        int main(){
        int num1;
        int total;

         printf("Enter a Number: ");
         scanf(" %d", &num1);


          total = num1 * num1;

          printf("The value of your number is %d", num1);
          printf("\n %d multiplied by %d is %d ", num1, num1, total);


         }
```

Comment: Your `printfs` don't seem to print what you want them to print. For example -- what is that first `printf` supposed to print? Also -- you are telling the second `printf` to print `num1` and `total` rather than `num1` and `num1`. Think more carefully about what you want to print, then print it. Also -- that last `scanf` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: "However, instead of multiplying itself, the square of the original number is multiplied" -- that isn't true, by the way. Your code computes `num1*num1` not `num1*num1*num1`. It seems that you are just *misreporting* what you have computed.

Comment: The first print asks the user to input a number. Would I get rid of the total? And i deleted the scanf to revise.

Comment: You are the one who put `total` where you did in the second `printf` -- don't put it there if you don't want to print it there. Perhaps you wanted to say something like `printf("\n %d multiplied by itself is %d\n", num1, total);`

Comment: If the user put 5 i would want the output to say, "5 multiplied by 5 is 25"

Comment: Your desired output lists three values in a single print statement; your code only prints two values.  It's not surprising that you don't get the output you want.  If you only want to pass `num1` and `total` once, use `printf("\n%1$d multiplied by %1$d is %2$d\n", num1, total)` — but that isn't the obvious solution — it uses a POSIX extension to [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
compared with Standard C.  End printing statements with newlines; it will save you grief over time.

Comment: You can use `num1` twice and `total` once in the `printf()`

Comment: I get the desired result of 5 multiplied by 5, but how would I insert the total in the print.

Comment: Okay, I managed to get the result. I updated the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but your output statements are messed up. Use:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
      int num1;
      int total;

      printf("Enter a Number: ");
      scanf(" %d", &num1);

      total = num1 * num1;

      printf("The value of your number is %d\n", num1);
      printf("%d multiplied by %d is %d\n", num1, num1, total);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Always validate every user-input. If a *matching failure* occurs, *Undefined Behavior* will result if you do not catch the error, e.g.

```
    fputs ("Enter a Number: ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %d", &num1) != 1) {    /* validate EVERY user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** the `space` in `" %d"` is superfluous. The `"%d"` conversion specifier ignores leading whitespace by default)

The compiler will concatenate adjacent string literals during compilation. There is no need for multiple `printf` statements -- but there is a need to accurately map an argument to each *conversion specifier* you include in your *format string*, e.g.

```
    /* compiler will concatenate adjacent strings */
    printf ("\nThe value of your number is %d\n"
            "%d multiplied by %d is %d\n",
            num1, num1, num1, total);
```

Complete Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num1;
    int total;

    fputs ("Enter a Number: ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %d", &num1) != 1) {    /* validate EVERY user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    total = num1 * num1;

    /* compiler will concatenate adjacent strings */
    printf ("\nThe value of your number is %d\n"
            "%d multiplied by %d is %d\n",
            num1, num1, num1, total);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readsquareint
Enter a Number: 25

The value of your number is 25
25 multiplied by 25 is 625
```

**Handling Overflow in Integer Multiplication**

You have one other consideration to be aware of. When squaring integer values, you run the risk of integer overflow saving the results back to type `int`. For example, `46340` can be squared and the results saved in `total`, but `46431` cannot.

A simple check to catch the overflow is to save the initial result of the multiplication in a type with a larger storage size and doing a quick division check to see if you get back a result that fits into an integer value, e.g.

```
    int num1, total;
    long long tmp;      /* temporary value to hold result of num1 * num1 */
    ...
    tmp = num1 * num1;  /* square value save results in tmp */

    if (num1 && tmp / num1 != num1) {   /* check for overflow */
        fputs ("error: overflow occurred in num1 * num1.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    total = tmp;
```

Per your comment, the complete code with the overflow test would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int num1, total;
    long long tmp;      /* temporary value to hold result of num1 * num1 */

    fputs ("Enter a Number: ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %d", &num1) != 1) {    /* validate EVERY user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    tmp = num1 * num1;  /* square value save results in tmp */

    if (num1 && tmp / num1 != num1) {   /* check for overflow */
        fputs ("error: overflow occurred in num1 * num1.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    total = tmp;

    /* compiler will concatenate adjacent strings */
    printf ("\nThe value of your number is %d\n"
            "%d multiplied by %d is %d\n",
            num1, num1, num1, total);
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do I input this code below my current to check it?

Comment: You would just substitute it adding the `long long tmp;` and changing `tmp = num1 * num1;` and adding the rest as shown above.